# In c# how do you make a field name different then when it is serialized?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that I have built from an XSD from a client.  The client XSD calls for a field named 3rdPartyTrackingNumber.  Because in c# I can't have a field that starts with a number I have named it ThirdPartyTrackingNumber.  Is there a meta tag or something that I can put on the column that will render it as 3rdartyTrackingNumber when serialized?

```
public class OSSShipmentGroup
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string shipmentNumber { get; set; }
    public object shipFrom { get; set; }
    public string carrierName { get; set; }

    [Some meta tag here]
    public string ThirdPartyTrackingNumber {get; set;}
    public OSSOrderDates dates { get; set; }
    public OSSOrderAddress[] address {get; set;}
    public OSSOrderShipmentItem[] containedItems { get; set; }
    public OSSShipmentInvoice[] invoice {get; set;}
}
```

I know I can implement ISerializable and make the changes in GetObjectData, but if it is only one field i was hoping I could just add a meta tag to the field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what serializer you are using. For example if you are using [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) which is the default in WCF `basicHttpBinding` and `wsHttpBinding` you could use the [`[DataMember]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attribute

```
[DataMember(Name = "ABC")]
public string ThirdPartyTrackingNumber { get; set; }
```

If you are using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) then the [`[XmlElement]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attribute should do the job:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "ABC")]
public string ThirdPartyTrackingNumber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For WCF, the normal process is to annotate the class with `[DataContract]`, an each property with `[DataMember]`, which has an optional `Name="foo"` property.

Note that by adding the class-level attribute you are saying "I will explicitly tell you which members to serialize; you can't then just annotate the one you want to rename.